Deployed app services receive values with comma instead of dots when reading double
I'm trying to deploy a weather application on an app services, it's a chatbot that takes a place, call for azure maps openai, receive coordinates and pass them to the weather API of Microsoft.
The problem is: when I test locally, my coordinates contain the dot and everything works fine, but when I deploy it online, coordinates are received with comma, and when I try to get the meteo information, I get an exception because commas are not allowed as a decimal separator.
What can I do?
I have tried replaces, cultureinfo, but I cannot see any difference on the deployed machine.
I even tried to change the default cultureinfo, in local I can get to make the comma appear, but when I try to do the same but inverse on the deployed machine nothing happens.
I'm building the resource the same way I was doing 1 week ago when everything worked fine, so I think changes are been taken correctly.
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"(atlasurl)&query={location}");
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-client-id", mapclientid);
            
                var geoResponse = client.Send(request);
                geoResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var geoResponseBody = geoResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var geocodeResult = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherGeoObject>(geoResponseBody);

            var geopoints = geocodeResult.Features[0].Geometry.Coordinates;
            most_probable_location = geocodeResult.Features[0].Properties.Address.FormattedAddress;
            string longitude = geopoints[0].ToString();
            string latitude = geopoints[1].ToString();
            request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, @$"weather_atlas{latitude},{longitude}");
            var weatherResponse = client.Send(request);

After the send request of weatherResponse, i receive error 400.
Keep in mind that this is my last state of code, I even tried to avoid the ToString, but i receive 400 always. 
Edit: Added code

This is all guesswork. Have you looked what culture is actually used on the server and on the client? What type do you use for coordinates?  With what and how do you look at the data? HAve you checked where the coordinates are formatted unexpectedly? On the server, on the transport on the client?


it's en US on pc, and it IT on the deployed one.
2)I have double for coordinates
3)Debugger on local, appinsight errors on the deployed one and i can see error 400 with coordinates like "query=12,1231232,14,123312331" where it should have been "query=12.1231232,14.123312331"
4)On the server, when i see the error i see the url bad formatted.


That is a self made format exchanged here between server&client? That is something that should not happen when using a standard format like JSON or XML as those are culture neutral defined when using standard serializer/deserializers.

I'm saying that because double does not know anything about comma or dot as decimal separator that a thing when doing a string representation somewhere.

i have a model that recieves the data and i parse the response into the model. But it's just a "List Coordinates {get,set}"

I tried to pass the value withouth using a to.String inside the url, but i have the same error with commas instead of dot

You really need show some code, so we can assess what could be causing this. A culture related problem should only occurr if you go from double=>string or string=>double (even if it's hidden somewhere, e.g. in serialization).

If you do the conversion yourself use an explicit culture. For transporting things that needs to be something like ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) for example.

i tried to CultureInfo(en-US) but it does not change anything ps code added

Your second HttpRequestMessage uses an invalid URI.

@Gaelix98 JSON uses dots for decimal separators. That's a fact. double is binary, it has no format. That's a fact. $"(atlasurl)&query={location}" is your own localized string interpolation code though. ToString() uses the current thread's locale to generate a string. Using ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) will use dots. It's the same with string interpolation. If you don't specify a culture, the current one is used.

@Gaelix98 separate the string format operations from the HTTP methods and use eg var url=String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,"weather_atlas{0},{1}",geopoints[0],geopoints[1]);.

I hope its becuase the decimal is converted to comma bases on the CuntureInfo of the deployed machine. Can you try the below code to see if it fix the issue.
string longitude = geopoints[0].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string latitude = geopoints[1].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

